# Can reliability and validity assessments be considered as required constituent of the "Measurement part" in Structural Equation Modeling?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, reliability, latent-variable, validity

I wonder if any type of reliability and / or validity analysis can be considered as an element of the Measurement part in SEM. For example, when computing Cronbach's alpha or the AVEs of an instrument, could it be said that they belong to the Measurement part of SEM, or belong to a separate category? A related question is: which statistics (if any) of the Measurement part can be considered as an assessment of reliability and validity for a given instrument?

Comment: I don't quite get what you're asking, but coefficient alpha makes some assumptions about the data, that are often not met - alpha assumes tau-equivalence of the measurement model. Composite reliability is preferred - if the assumptions are met, then alpha is composite reliability.

Answer (score 0):

After reading literature about the topic, I can say that: 1) SEM, and more specifically Confirmatory Factor Analysis (measurement part of SEM) complement the psychometric analysis of one scale, so it provides useful insights about some reliability and validity features of the scale under consideration. And, 2) examples of these useful insights are convergent and discriminant validity.